# Writing EXIF metadata to images in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, metadata, exif

I want to store some metadata in images. My camera application gives me a bitmap, which I store in the storage (MediaStore) device. In addition to this, I want to add a few tags to the picture in its metadata. I think EXIF is a good way of doing this. But I couldn't find good references on how to do this.

If there are some tools to achieve this task in Android programming, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: ExifInterface can be somewhat unreliable -- I have seen it corrupt EXIF data in certain circumstances. A more reliable option that handles more EXIF tags (including custom EXIF tags) is Sanselan Android. http://code.google.com/p/sanselanandroid/ Usage samples for Sanselan Android are here: http://massapi.com/source/sanselan-0.97-incubator/src/test/java/org/apache/sanselan/sampleUsage/WriteExifMetadataExample.java.html

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/dragon66/pixymeta-android)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, Somebody (offline) pointed me to a useful resource. The `ExifInterface` looks like what I was searching for. [Android-er](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/12/read-exif-information-in-jpeg-file.html) has a post demonstrating how to read EXIF metadata in Android and I think writing should not be very different.

I don't know, but can we EXIF to write arbitrary metadata, ie. other than those specified in the [ExifInterface documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) (like latitude, longitude, flash etc). If not, what could be a preferred method of writing arbitrary metadata to image files?

Thanks

Comment: Could you make a new question from your 2nd paragraph so we can answer it properly? (IMHO the answer is Yes)

Comment: just did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901971/writing-arbitrary-metadata-to-exif-in-android

Comment: I've also found this library useful: https://github.com/dragon66/pixymeta-android

Answer (score 10):

```
public static void writeFile (File photo, double latitude, double longitude) throws IOException{
    ExifInterface exif = null;

    try{
        Log.v("latiDouble", ""+latitude);
        Log.v("longiDouble", ""+longitude);
        exif = new ExifInterface(photo.getCanonicalPath());
        if (exif != null) { 
            double latitu = latitude;
            double longitu = longitude;
            double alat = Math.abs(latitu);
            double along = Math.abs(longitu);
            String stringLati = convertDoubleIntoDegree(alat);
            String stringLongi = convertDoubleIntoDegree(along);
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, stringLati);
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, stringLongi);
            Log.v("latiString", ""+ stringLati);
            Log.v("longiString", ""+ stringLongi);
            exif.saveAttributes();
            String lati = exif.getAttribute (ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
            String longi = exif.getAttribute (ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
            Log.v("latiResult", ""+ lati);
            Log.v("longiResult", ""+ longi);
        } 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I copied the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644873/android-write-exif-gps-latitude-and-longitude-onto-jpeg-failed)

Comment: why do u abs latitude longitude?)

Comment: Thank you for your question, I double checked the code. yes it is correct to use ABS, as the plus & minus appears in exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, lat>0?"N":"S"); and in exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, lon>0?"E":"W");

Comment: I mean code you posted here only uses positive values and ignores negative. I know that both are used in formulas usually but not in your code you posted here

Comment: In my code the positive and negative values are translated  to N & S and E & W. SO they are not ignored.