# Android write EXIF GPS Latitude and Longitude onto JPEG failed

Tags: android, gps, location, jpeg, exif

I would like to add GPS data such as longitude and latitude into the jpeg photo.
The photo is captured by tabbing the card (NFC) 
In the logcat correct values can be displayed but these values cannot be written into the jpg photo file !

Below is my code:
It is used to take saved jpg files and call the method below
The method is used to add EXIF GPS parameters into the jpg
The GPS parameters such as longitude and latitude are already taken in another activity.

I use EXIF Viewer in Firefox to see the result.

Does the position for the IO Exception matters?

The following is the important log cat log which may render the failure:
07-26 11:48:30.386: D/NativeNfcTag(195): Tag lost, restarting polling loop

```
 public static void writeFile (File photo, double latitude, double longitude) throws IOException{


    ExifInterface exif = null;

    try{
        Log.v("latiDouble", ""+latitude);
        Log.v("longiDouble", ""+longitude);
        exif = new ExifInterface(photo.getCanonicalPath());
        if (exif != null) {
        double latitu = latitude;
        double longitu = longitude;
        double alat = Math.abs(latitu);
        double along = Math.abs(longitu);
        String stringLati = convertDoubleIntoDegree(alat);
        String stringLongi = convertDoubleIntoDegree(along);
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, stringLati);            
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, stringLongi);
        Log.v("latiString", ""+ stringLati);
        Log.v("longiString", ""+ stringLongi);
        exif.saveAttributes();
        String lati = exif.getAttribute (ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);  
         String longi = exif.getAttribute (ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);  
         Log.v("latiResult", ""+ lati);
         Log.v("longiResult", ""+ longi);

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

The below is the position to call the method
...

```
    Cursor locationCursor = dbHandler.fetchGpsLocationTypeByAttendInfoID(attendInfoId);
      if (locationCursor.getCount()>0) {
        double latitude = dbHandler.fetchDoubleItem(locationCursor,"LATITUDE");
        double longitude = dbHandler.fetchDoubleItem(locationCursor,"LONGITUDE");


            Log.v("latitude",""+latitude);
            Log.v("latitude",""+longitude);     

            try {
                GpsUtils.writeFile(photoFile, latitude, longitude);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
    dbHandler.close();

    cameraHandler.startPreview();
```

Comment: We'll probably need more information on what your code does (stepping through it and explaining what each line does might lead you to a solution, too) and any research you've already done for the question. For example, if you get an exception, what's the exception? Basically, if it's something you think can help someone answering the question, it'd be great to add it.

Comment: What I have seen is that the parameters set is valid and able to be displayed from the logcat but however when opening the iamges by EXIF Viewer of Firefox , I can't see any GPS data written in this picture.

Answer (score 14):

Ok, I struggled with this for a long time but finally got it.  Last time I used it this code worked:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(imgFile.getCanonicalPath());
              //String latitudeStr = "90/1,12/1,30/1";
              double lat = location.getLatitude();
              double alat = Math.abs(lat);
              String dms = Location.convert(alat, Location.FORMAT_SECONDS);
              String[] splits = dms.split(":");
              String[] secnds = (splits[2]).split("\\.");
              String seconds;
              if(secnds.length==0)
              {
                  seconds = splits[2];
              }
              else
              {
                  seconds = secnds[0];
              }

              String latitudeStr = splits[0] + "/1," + splits[1] + "/1," + seconds + "/1";
              exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, latitudeStr);

              exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, lat>0?"N":"S");

              double lon = location.getLongitude();
              double alon = Math.abs(lon);


              dms = Location.convert(alon, Location.FORMAT_SECONDS);
              splits = dms.split(":");
              secnds = (splits[2]).split("\\.");

              if(secnds.length==0)
              {
                  seconds = splits[2];
              }
              else
              {
                  seconds = secnds[0];
              }
              String longitudeStr = splits[0] + "/1," + splits[1] + "/1," + seconds + "/1";


              exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, longitudeStr);
              exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, lon>0?"E":"W");

              exif.saveAttributes();

          }
```

Comment: Where the IOexception should be placed ?

Comment: Did you resave the file when you are done?  This code works for me and EXIF viewer sees the embedded position - I just tested it.

Comment: what else should I save besides adding  exif.saveAttributes(); ?

And which software is the best to check the EXIF ?

Comment: I used the EXIF viewer in Firefox.  I sent the file to myself from my phone, opened it with that viewer then scrolled down and it showed the GPS.  It even provided links to show the location on google maps and it was spot on.  Are you sure you have a valid GPS location?

Comment: When I use https://maps.google.com/ and enter the co-ordinate as
22.3071491,114.1719491

it is valid

Comment: Sorry, dunno what the problem is then, I know it should work and is for me.

Comment: when I use FxiF , the insertion of GPS data is successful

Comment: Hi Kaediil.. i wanna ask about this code, how to running in javascript? I need for take picture with geolocation in my android device. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me ,are you talking about how to display the Geo information in the webpage using javascript ?

Comment: I needed to implement the following fix: `splits[0] + "/1," + splits[1] + "/1," + seconds.replace(',','.') + "/1";`