# How to rotate photograph without losing Exif and Metadata?

Tags: android, exif, image-rotation, android-2.2-froyo

In Android 2.2 is there a way to rotate a photograph without losing the Exif and other metadata?  I tried using the Matrix class but it drops the metadata.

Answer (score 3):

You could read the EXIF data, rotate the image, and then write the EXIF data.  [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) has been available since API 5.  I found an example of writing exif here:  [Android write EXIF GPS Latitude and Longitude onto JPEG failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11644873/android-write-exif-gsp-latitude-and-longitude-onto-jpeg-failed)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research (Nov 2012), there is no way to preserve the exif metadata automatically if you resize the image (or otherwise process it via the Bitmap* classes).

You must specifically retrieve and copy the exif properties by name. This blog post was very helpful:

http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/17/android-re-size-image-without-loosing-exif-information/

And I wrote up my own experience here:

[Android Image Resizing and Preserving EXIF data (Orientation, Rotation, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596500/android-image-resizing-and-preserving-exif-data-orientation-rotation-etc)