# Writing location coordinates to exif changes location

Tags: android, android-location

I have an app published on Google Play, which at some point fetches the users geographical location and saves it with a picture. I have however now gotten reports from a few Brazilian users complaining about the pictures are getting GeoTagged in Saudi Arabia. Have only gotten this complaint from users in Brazil and I am by no means what so ever able to reproduce the issue myself.

**What could be causing this?**

// I save and read the location in an ExifInterface with this "book"..

```
// Write Geotag and time to Image's Exif
public Boolean writeExifData(Location location, Date date, String filepath){

    // Determine if we got a location
    boolean isLocationOn = false;
    if(location != null){ isLocationOn = true; }

    try {
        // Set up exif 
        ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);

        if(isLocationOn){
            // Get location values
            double latitude = location.getLatitude();
            double longitude = location.getLongitude();
            float accuracy = location.getAccuracy();

            // Convert Latitude and Longitude
            int num1Lat = (int)Math.floor(latitude);
            int num2Lat = (int)Math.floor((latitude - num1Lat) * 60);
            double num3Lat = (latitude - ((double)num1Lat+((double)num2Lat/60))) * 3600000;

            int num1Lon = (int)Math.floor(longitude);
            int num2Lon = (int)Math.floor((longitude - num1Lon) * 60);
            double num3Lon = (longitude - ((double)num1Lon+((double)num2Lon/60))) * 3600000;

            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE, num1Lat+"/1,"+num2Lat+"/1,"+num3Lat+"/1000");
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE, num1Lon+"/1,"+num2Lon+"/1,"+num3Lon+"/1000");

            if (latitude > 0) {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "N"); 
            }else {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF, "S");
            }

            if (longitude > 0) {
                exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "E");    
            }else {
            exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF, "W");
            }

            // Add accuracy to exif
            String accuracy_value = String.valueOf(Math.round(accuracy));
            exif.setAttribute("UserComment", "accuracy=" + accuracy_value);
        }

        // Add capture time to exif
        exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME, date.toString());

        // Save exif
        exif.saveAttributes();

        Log.v(Constants.TAG_ALERT_PROCESS, "Wrote data to Exif successfully");
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.v(Constants.TAG_ALERT_PROCESS, "Failed writing data to Exif with error: " + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    } 
}

public Object_ImageExifData readExifData(String filePath){
    Helper_ExifGeoConverter geoConverter;
    Location location = null;
    ExifInterface exif;

    // Format filePath String (remove "file://" )
    if(filePath.startsWith("file://")){
        filePath = filePath.replace("file://", "");
    }

    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(filePath);
        if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE) != null){

            geoConverter = new Helper_ExifGeoConverter(exif);
            location = new Location("");
            float float_lat = geoConverter.getLatitude();
            location.setLatitude(float_lat);
            float float_lon = geoConverter.getLongitude();
            location.setLongitude(float_lon);

            /** Get accuracy. Accuracy is stored
              * under the tag UserComment as "accuracy=xx"*/
            if(exif.getAttribute("UserComment") != null){
                String value = exif.getAttribute("UserComment");
                value = value.replace("accuracy=", "");
                float accuracy = Integer.parseInt(value);
                location.setAccuracy(accuracy);
            } 

            // Get capture time
            String time = "";
            if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME) != null){
                time = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
            }

            return new Object_ImageExifData(location, time);
        }else{

            // Get capture time
            String time = "xx.xx.xxxx";
            if(exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME) != null){
                time = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_DATETIME);
            }

            return new Object_ImageExifData(location, time);
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("myTag", "Failed to read exif data");
        return null;
    }
}

public class Helper_ExifGeoConverter{

    private boolean valid = false;
    Float Latitude, Longitude;

    Helper_ExifGeoConverter(ExifInterface exif) {
        String attrLATITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE);
        String attrLATITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF);
        String attrLONGITUDE = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE);
        String attrLONGITUDE_REF = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF);

        if ((attrLATITUDE != null) && (attrLATITUDE_REF != null)
                && (attrLONGITUDE != null) && (attrLONGITUDE_REF != null)) {
            valid = true;

            if (attrLATITUDE_REF.equals("N")) {
                Latitude = convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE);
            } else {
                Latitude = 0 - convertToDegree(attrLATITUDE);
            }

            if (attrLONGITUDE_REF.equals("E")) {
                Longitude = convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE);
            } else {
                Longitude = 0 - convertToDegree(attrLONGITUDE);
            }

        }
    }

    private Float convertToDegree(String stringDMS){
         Float result;
         String[] DMS = stringDMS.split(",", 3);

         String[] stringD = DMS[0].split("/", 2);
         Double D0 = Double.valueOf(stringD[0]);
         Double D1 = Double.valueOf(stringD[1]);
         Double FloatD = D0/D1;

         String[] stringM = DMS[1].split("/", 2);
         Double M0 = Double.valueOf(stringM[0]);
         Double M1 = Double.valueOf(stringM[1]);
         Double FloatM = M0/M1;

         String[] stringS = DMS[2].split("/", 2);
         Double S0 = Double.valueOf(stringS[0]);
         Double S1 = Double.valueOf(stringS[1]);
         Double FloatS = S0/S1;

         result = new Float(FloatD + (FloatM/60) + (FloatS/3600));

         return result;
    }
```

**SOLUTION**
With the help of @greenapps I came to realize that I was, when writing to Exif, converting location from decimal format to degrees, minutes, seconds format falsely. Used [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11651345/1692590) instead.

Comment: I couldn't see the line causing this error but just in case you didn't notice, (-23.548405, -46.640618) in Brazil and (23.548405, 46.640618) in Saudi Arabia, for example. You got any other complaints form that continent? I don't see any location manipulation here, maybe when saving it to the database, you take the absolute value or something like that.

Comment: huh, good spot - would be a good explanation. But, if this is the case (I somehow use the absolute value instead), no users in any negative coordinated area (or how to put it) would get a correct location. Which I'm pretty sure is not what's happening. Now I live on like 55,12 so I wouldn't know for sure, but I haven't gotten any complaints about this from people besides Brazil.

Comment: I have never used that feature but I know in AVD, we have the option to simulate any coordinates we like. Then, you might be able to debug your code. Look at this page http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/mobile/providing-gps-coordinates-via-the-eclipse-android-simulator.html

Comment: Perfect, you are just thinking way faster that me - you can do the same on device with MockLocation apps, hope I'll track the bug down, thanks

Comment: I'm not, believe me. It's just a couple of sad experiences :) I'm glad they are of some use now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put geo lat/lon tags in the exif info of a jpg then all lat/lons are positive. You also have to set a E/O and N/S tag. Are you doing that?

Comment: Yes, I am saving it in exif as hours, minutes, seconds format

Comment: Sorry but that is no answer to my question. Reread again please.

Comment: Oh, excuse me, misunderstood. I am not quite sure what you mean by E/O, N/S tags - but I added the conversion/exif save and read code to the question

Comment: East/west and north/south tag indicate +/-.

Comment: Yes, that I am doing that - I actually by now think I am reading the exif wrong then

Comment: You are writing it wrong i think. You can easily test your app if it writes negative values ok by just putting known negative values in and checking with an external app/program. Try with the Brazilian ones ;-).

Comment: In a separate ExifViewer app I can see image GeoTag value, which in one case is: GPSLatitude: -15/1,45/1,53984/1000 GPSLatitudeRef: S GPSLongitude: -52/1,4/1,28986/1000 GPSLongitudeRef: W - Am I mistaken if this isn't correct for a location in Brazil?

Comment: That is an incorrect viewer as it only is allowed to contain positive values for degrees/minutes/seconds. If you put in those negative values the viewer should not have shown them as negative but should have interpreted as unsigned. That would have given a very different value. Use another program/app to test.

Comment: huh, when reading, I remove the leading "-"s from values before converting them to decimal format, and that worked the location is now showing in Brazil, so guess I am writing it wrong, which I'll dig into now - thanks

Comment: Advice: first do the writing and check with external app if you put a good exif geo tag. You can also upload pictures to online services who then show the location on a map. After that implement the reading. IrfanView is good also. And as said before: at reading there should not be negative values. So removing a "-" is complete nonsense. Don't write negative values to begin with.

Comment: The issue is in the writing code, removing the "-" before converting just confirmed that. I can't really "accept your answer", but you sure helped me a whole lot in tracking down the bug, so thanks for that, cheers

Comment: Why cant you accept my answer? The first thing i said is that you had to write only positive values. The second that negative/positive had to be implemented by north/south and east/west tag. Do you want to have it any better? Please tell me.