# Writing arbitrary metadata to EXIF in Android

Tags: android, metadata, exif

This question originated here: [Writing EXIF metadata to images in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245811/writing-exif-metadata-to-images-in-android/3246501?noredirect=1#comment22637008_3246501) .

Can we use EXIF to write arbitrary metadata, i.e. other than those specified in the [ExifInterface documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) (like latitude, longitude, flash etc). If not, what could be a preferred method of writing arbitrary metadata to image files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ExifInterface is only a very limited implementation of the EXIF standard and will not allow you to read/write tags other than the ones documented/defined. In the chosen answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944123/reading-android-jpeg-exif-metadata-from-picture-callback) an alternative method is described.

Arbitrary data could be written to one of the following tags

```
Tag-hex     Tag-dec IFD     Key                             Type    
0x010e      270     Image   Exif.Image.ImageDescription     Ascii
0x9286      37510   Photo   Exif.Photo.UserComment          Comment
```

whereby UserComment has less restrictions regarding the character set used

Comment: I cannot test this now, but I'm marking this as an answer because it seems reasonable to me that the suggested approach would work.

Comment: You can always remove the mark later if it turns out it didn't fly or someone provided a better solution ... good luck!